Find the maximal region in $\mathbb C$ in which the following series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2}{n+4}z^n$ is uniformly convergent

Find the maximal region in $\mathbb C$ in which the following series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2}{n+4}z^n$ is uniformly convergent
I would like some help with this question.

The series seems to be a power series, so I tried to compute the radius of convergence to use Cauchy-Hadamard, but am stuck on how to take the limit $$\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty }|\sqrt[n]{a_n}|=\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty }\left| \frac{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2}{n+4} \right|^\frac 1n$$ considering the fact that the numerator and denominator are binomials. That is, it's a bit unclear how I can simplify this expression to be able to apply elementary limits.
I also tried the alternative ratio version $$\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty }\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|= \frac{(-1)^{3(n+1)}(n+1)-(n+1)^2}{(n+1)+4}\cdot  \frac{n+4}{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2},$$ but this seems to have the same issue with the binomial terms not cancelling easily.

They are a lot of equivalent characterisations of the convergence radius, you can use simpler ones. Notice that $a_n \sim -n$

It should be one according to your last $\limsup$. Use the dominance of $n^2$ terms.

If $S$ is the sum $$z^4,S=\frac{ z (12-2 z-18 z^2+3 z^3+3 z^4   )} {(1-z)^2 (z+1) }+4 \log \left((1-z)^4 (z+1)\right)$$

@ClaudeLeibovici come on man, how do you find that! Stunning.

@TurquoiseTilt. Guess what  ? Mathematica

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{3(n+1)}(n+1)-(n+1)^2}{(n+1)+4}}{\frac{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2}{n+4}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n+4)((-1)^{3(n+1)}(n+1)-(n+1)^2)}{(n+5)((-1)^{3n}n-n^2)}\right|=\\\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{-n^3+(-1)^{3 (n+1)} n^2-6 n^2+5 (-1)^{3 (n+1)} n-9 n+4 (-1)^{3 (n+1)}-4}{-n^3+(-1)^{3 n} n^2-5 n^2+5 (-1)^{3 n} n}\right|=1$$
Thus we conclude that it is uniformly convergent on set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. For $z=1$ it is clearly not convergent since we get $\displaystyle\sum a_n$ and $a_n\not\to0$. We should now check if it is uniformly convergent for all other $|z|=1,z\ne 1$. We can write $z=e^{i\theta},\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]\setminus\{0\}$. Now we get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2}{n+4}e^{i n\theta}=\\\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2}{n+4}(\cos{n\theta}+i\sin{n\theta})=\\\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2}{n+4}\cos{n\theta}+i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2}{n+4}\sin(n\theta)$$
It's easily shown that these two series are not uniformly convergent. In fact,$\frac{(-1)^{3n}n-n^2}{n+4}\sim -n$ and $\sum(-n)\cos{(n\theta)}$ obviously isn't uniformly convergent, since for any $\theta\ne \frac{\pi}{2},\theta\ne\frac{-\pi}{2}$ this series diverges, Similiarly $\sum (-n)\sin(n\theta)$ diverges for all $\theta\ne\pi$. Hence the largest set on which the given series is uniformly convergent is $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$.

Thank you! Do you mind elaborating on this part: "It's easily shown that these two series are not uniformly convergent".
The two series are independent of $z$, so how do you show that they are not uniformly convergent in $z$?

@pushvar here, I edited my answer.

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)^2((-1)^{3(n+1)}/(n+1)^2-1)}{(n+1)(1+4/(n+1))}\cdot\frac{n(1+4/n)}{n^2((-1)^{3n}/n^2-1)}$$
for $n\to \infty $ we can see that the oscillating terms go to zero and we have
$$\require{cancel} \frac{-n^2}{n}\cdot\frac{n}{-n^2} = 1$$
so radius of convergence is $R=1$ from this we know that the convergence is uniform for each $\rho >0$ such that $0<\rho<R$. Since $a_n\to \infty$ we can't say nothing about convergence on the boundary.

I hope this helps!

It's possible to check convergence on boundary, too, I'm pretty sure. I'll give an answer in a minute.

@bb_823 the result I'm familiar with need $a_n\to 0$ so I'm not able to prove it. Very curious to see your shot!

I posted it. Check it out and correct me if I made a mistake.
